# How to save the google maps style state and drawable background? (Shared Preferences)

Tags: android, google-maps, sharedpreferences

I need to save the color style state of the map, I tried with this but it does not work using SharedPreferences I do not know how to do it, I only give option to change the type of red and dark map another?
Does anyone know how to do it?

```
 if(sharedPreferences != null){
        if(sharedPreferences.getInt("Estatus", CLARO) == 1){
            mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapconocegentecustom));
            mMapD.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapconocegentecustom));
            mMapM.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapconocegentecustom));
        }else if(sharedPreferences.getInt("Estatus", OSCURO) == 0){
            mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapdarkcustom));
            mMapD.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapdarkcustom));
            mMapM.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapdarkcustom));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me the code of saving data to SharePreferences?

Comment: Just i put this, 'redPreferences.edit().putInt("Estatus", CLARO).apply();' @SanKoKo

Comment: Do you get the saved data from sharepreferences?